# Connecting usb to galaxy core I8262

Tags: samsung

Is there any possible way to connect a usb flash drive or thumb drive to Samsung galaxy core I8262. ....

Answer (score 0):

No. This phone doesn't support [usb-on-the-go](/questions/tagged/usb-on-the-go).

Answer (score -1):

It may support

1. root your galaxy core i8262
2. install stickMount

then connect any usb drives on it.